# How to push the changes to chef server via Berks install & berks upload when ever cookbooks are pushed to Git Master

Tags: chef-infra, bitbucket, berkshelf

We'd like to enforce a policy where once we merge to master and increase the chef cookbook version, it automatically runs Berks install & berks upload.
Also, we'd like to receive recommendations on cookbook versioning. of 0.x.x. versus 1.x.x

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific answer, look up all of the various CI/CD tools and services out there and then write some scripts to do what you want. We don't offer opinion-based tool recommendations on StackOverflow because there is no single answer. Use what works best for you and your teams.